# Android TCP: error EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: java, android, tcp, wifi

I'm using a TCP connection in my android app. The connection runs in a dedicated thread.

My code:

```
class ReceiverThread extends Thread {
Handler handler;

ReceiverThread(Handler h) {
    handler = h;
}

@Override
public void run() {


    try {
            socketTCP = new Socket((SERVERIP), SERVERPORT);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socketTCP.getInputStream()));
            socketTCP.setSoTimeout(20000);

            while (TCPRunning) {

                String strTcp = in.readLine().toString();
                i++;
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("getStr", strTcp + "\n");
                msg.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(msg);

            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.v("TcpClient", "Unknown host");
            try {
                socketTCP.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // Erreur TimeOut
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("getStr", "Error");
            msg.setData(b);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (socketTCP != null) {
                try {
                    socketTCP.close();
                    socketTCP = null;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } finally {
            try {
                i = 0;
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (socketTCP != null) {
                    socketTCP.close();
                    socketTCP = null;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Then I connect the android device to the wifi of the other device, when i launch my app; it works well : I receive data send by the other device.
When I stop the connection and start again (a few seconds later) it works.

But when i wait for 2 or 3 minutes, then the connection became impossible:

I get the following exception:

```
02-25 10:40:32.638: W/System.err(4384): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 50000): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
02-25 10:40:32.648: W/System.err(4384):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
02-25 10:40:32.648: W/System.err(4384):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-25 10:40:32.648: W/System.err(4384):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
02-25 10:40:32.648: W/System.err(4384):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
02-25 10:40:32.648: W/System.err(4384):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
02-25 10:40:32.658: W/System.err(4384):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
02-25 10:40:32.658: W/System.err(4384):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
02-25 10:40:32.658: W/System.err(4384):     at nke.service.wificonnection.ThreadWifi$ReceiverThread.run(ThreadWifi.java:163)
02-25 10:40:32.658: W/System.err(4384): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
02-25 10:40:32.658: W/System.err(4384):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
02-25 10:40:32.658: W/System.err(4384):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
02-25 10:40:32.668: W/System.err(4384):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-25 10:40:32.668: W/System.err(4384):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-25 10:40:32.668: W/System.err(4384):     ... 7 more
```

If I want to use again the connection, I have to refresh wifi connection (in parameters of Android, stop and restart wifi and connect to the wifi of the device).

What could be the problem?  Is there a problem when I close the socket after error?

Answer (score 1):

The `EHOSTUNREACH` error means that the destination is not responding.

There are basically a few ways this can happen:

- The datalink layer has gone away (i.e. WiFi has dropped)
- The routing table has changed and packets are no longer arriving at the desired destination
- A firewall is causing packets to be dropped.
- The remote host is not responding to the connection request (port probably closed but filtered)

You can try connecting to other ports on the destination.  If that works when your app doesn't, then the receiving (server) app is no longer listening.  If all ports that were accessible are suddenly not, then it's your WiFi or routing table or general firewall issue.

You can still have a valid IP route to that a host but if it is *filtering* connection requests for security reasons, you'll get this error.  Filtering is common for closed ports so that port-scans of the device don't reveal anything but an empty hole as though nothing was at that address.  I couldn't find any definitive reference that Android does this but it seems likely.

Comment: if I call the same request with browser from my mobile I am getting proper response ..